# Using getUserMedia() on insecure origins in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, getusermedia

I am developing a webpage that uses camera. When I test in Chrome in my local network, camera doesn't work and I get warning in the console:

> getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.

In the link provided there is an instruction to set some flags in Chrome. So I tried. My command looks like this:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="192.168.0.15" --user-data-dir=c:\chrome-dev-profile

But when I run Chrome I get this message:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure. Stability and security will suffer.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way I can test in local network without setting up `https` server? I need this just for development.

Answer (score 1):

Luka,

I've run into this bug just yesterday. I have not found out how to get Chrome to honor that flag on the command line yet. But I did find a workaround that works for my case.

I'm running my web services on a Linux machine that is running an ssh server. I'm testing on windows with chrome, and used putty to connect to the linux box from windows and then created a "local port forward" to make my remote linux box's ipaddress:port appear on localhost:port on windows. Depending on your platform this workaround may work for you. This approach isn't too cumbersome if you only have a few ports to forward.

In my particular case my setting for putty looked like
L8080 localhost:8080

To see more about port forwarding and ssh see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding